# Change the order of Stacked Bar Chart in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been struggling for a few hours to change the order of stacked bar chart.

I looked at two SO threads: [How to change stacking order in stacked bar chart in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33538059/how-to-change-stacking-order-in-stacked-bar-chart-in-r) and [How to control ordering of stacked bar chart using identity on ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345923/how-to-control-ordering-of-stacked-bar-chart-using-identity-on-ggplot2)

Both of these threads use rev() function in factor(). However, for some reason, this doesn't work for me.

Here's my code: 
(The version in which "D" appears at the top in bar and in legend)

```
a<-as.data.frame(list(ID=c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4"),Num = c(1,2,3,4)))
b<-as.data.frame(list(ID=c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4"),Num = c(4,3,2,1)))
d<-as.data.frame(list(ID=c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4"),Num = c(5,8,9,10)))

a$type <- c("A")
b$type <- c("B")
d$type <- c("d")
c<-rbind(a,b,d)
c$type <- factor(c$type,levels = rev(c$type))

windows()
ggplot(data = c, aes(x = ID, y = Num, fill = type)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Now, I want to reverse this by having "A" at the top both in the bar chart and in the legend. 
I tried this code:

```
a<-as.data.frame(list(ID=c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4"),Num = c(1,2,3,4)))
b<-as.data.frame(list(ID=c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4"),Num = c(4,3,2,1)))
d<-as.data.frame(list(ID=c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4"),Num = c(5,8,9,10)))

a$type <- c("A")
b$type <- c("B")
d$type <- c("d")
c<-rbind(a,b,d)
c$type <- factor(c$type,levels = c$type)



windows()
ggplot(data = c, aes(x = ID, y = Num, fill = type)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

This reverses the order in the legend but not the order in the bar chart. I still see the order D-> B -> A. I am really frustrated.

Can someone please help me? I'd appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: Use `unique` to get rid of duplicate levels, or you'll run into problems. To clean up: `c$type <- droplevels(c$type)`

Comment: Alistaire, Thanks for your help. I added the code mentioned by you. However, ggplots still spits out D, B and A. Could you please help me ? Do you want me to post the code?

Comment: Ok. It seems that I need to sort the data first. Here's the thread I looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345923/how-to-control-ordering-of-stacked-bar-chart-using-identity-on-ggplot2?noredirect=1&lq=1. Here's the code I used: c<-c[order(c$type, decreasing = T),] This fixed the issue.

Comment: Part of the confusion is that ggplot2's behavior has changed in recent versions. For a long time, setting the factor level order worked, but now you need to sort the data frame.

Comment: @joran That should be an answer.